# Does Iron Fist Barb level depend on current barbarian level?

Tags: clash-of-clans

The Kings ability summons Barb's and the Queen's ability summons archers. Do the level of these troops depend on the level of the troop itself or on the level of the hero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summoned troops level are equal to the level of the troops in your laboratory.

> if you can train level 5 Barbarians, the Barbarian King will summon Level 5 Barbarians

The same goes for the Archer Queen.

[CoC wiki](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Barbarian_King) sums this up.

Just for clarification:

In the link they say that:

> Starting at level 5, the Barbarian King obtains an ability called Iron Fist which can be used on the battlefield. It partially heals him, summons up to 30 additional Barbarians, and grants the Barbarian King and his summoned Barbarians increased damage and speed. This does not stack with the Rage Spell, and does not affect any other troops, including other Barbarians belonging to the regular army. **This ability gets more powerful every fifth level**

With the ability getting stronger, they mean that:

- More barbarians are summoned
- They get a greater damage boost
- They get a greater speed boost

<sub>"They" refers to the king and the summoned minions</sub>